# How to kill a saga action?

Tags: redux-saga, saga

I have a problem, I authenticate my user, when the authentication is done, I execute some actions.

one of those actions is executed after a while, let's say 60000 ms.

Like that :

```
yield delay(60000);
yield put(myAction);
```

Now when The user logs out, before 60000, let's say he logged in and logged out immediatly in 5 seconds, and log in again, the previous action will be executed after 55 seconds mathematically, because it is not killed, the process is there in the background, and it will be executed again in just 5 seconds ( the new action after the second log in ).

I want that when I log out, some actions that I was waiting to execute them after a while just disappear and stop running in the background.

Any ideas ? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The only way I can think of to stop a currently executing action would be to have it check something external and stop itself. Redux saga has channels to allow you to prevent actions of the same type from operation at the same time. They might be useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options would be using the [`race`](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#raceeffects) effect.

> It instructs the middleware to run a *Race* between multiple Effects. When resolving a *Race*, the middleware automatically **cancels all the losing** *Effects*

So you can create a race between authentication handler and logout listener:

```
function* authenticate() {
  // ...
  yield delay(60000);
  yield put(myAction);
}

function* handleAuthRequest() {
  yield race([
    authenticate(),
    take(LOGOUT),
  ]);
}
```

`authenticate` will be canceled if `LOGOUT` action will be dispatched before its completion.

---

If you need this in several places, you can create reusable wrapper. Something like:

```
const withCancel = (saga, cancelPattern) =>
  function* cancelWrapper(...args) {
    yield race([
      take(cancelPattern),
      saga(...args),
    ]);
  };
```